# How to make hover effect only on hamburger button, not on close button?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the following code :

```
.btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::before{
  transform: translateY(-0.5875rem);
}
.btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::after{
  transform: translateY(0.5875rem);
}
```

How to make this hover code only work in the state of the hamburger button, not on the close button?

```js
$('.btn-menu').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

```css
.btn-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 38px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.btn-menu__bars {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
}
.btn-menu__bars:before, .btn-menu__bars:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.btn-menu__bars:before {
  transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
.btn-menu__bars:after {
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
}
.menu-open .btn-menu .btn-menu__bars:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-open .btn-menu .btn-menu__bars:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* How to make this only on burger, not on close */
.btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::before{
  transform: translateY(-0.5875rem);
}
.btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::after{
  transform: translateY(0.5875rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-menu" type="button" style="background-color: red;">
  <i class="btn-menu__bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you add `.menu-open` to the body, you need to apply the hover effect when the body doesn't have the class with `:not`.

```
body:not(.menu-open) .btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::before{
  transform: translateY(-0.5875rem);
}
body:not(.menu-open) .btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::after{
  transform: translateY(0.5875rem);
}
```

```js
$('.btn-menu').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

```css
.btn-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 38px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.btn-menu__bars {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
}
.btn-menu__bars:before, .btn-menu__bars:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.btn-menu__bars:before {
  transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
.btn-menu__bars:after {
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
}
.menu-open .btn-menu .btn-menu__bars:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-open .btn-menu .btn-menu__bars:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

body:not(.menu-open) .btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::before{
  transform: translateY(-0.5875rem);
}
body:not(.menu-open) .btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::after{
  transform: translateY(0.5875rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-menu" type="button" style="background-color: red;">
  <i class="btn-menu__bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Also your script without JQuery :

```
document.querySelector(".btn-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("menu-open")
})
```

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("menu-open")
})
```

```css
.btn-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 38px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.btn-menu__bars {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
}
.btn-menu__bars:before, .btn-menu__bars:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.btn-menu__bars:before {
  transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
.btn-menu__bars:after {
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
}
.menu-open .btn-menu .btn-menu__bars:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-open .btn-menu .btn-menu__bars:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

body:not(.menu-open) .btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::before{
  transform: translateY(-0.5875rem);
}
body:not(.menu-open) .btn-menu:hover .btn-menu__bars::after{
  transform: translateY(0.5875rem);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-menu" type="button" style="background-color: red;">
  <i class="btn-menu__bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Note that if you only have 1 element with a class, you can use an id (and then use `getElementById()` instead).

Comment: @HereticMonkey He is using JQuery, it's not the topic, but I give the vanilla js solution in complement in the second part of my answer.